# TextFSM Template Issue: sh ip mroute

Tags: netmiko, python-textfsm

I am using Netmiko with Textfsm to run some commands using Python scripts on an `ASR1006` with `IOS-XE`. Everything is working well, but when I run `show mroute`, I encounter the following error: `TextFSMError: State Error raised. Rule Line: 29. Input Line: Bidir-Upstream: TenGigabitEthernet0/0/2`.

Please advise
Thanks in advance

I expect this command to retrieve the following information: `(*,224.0.0.0/4), 00:36:12/-, RP 10.6.227.1, flags: B, Bidir-Upstream: TenGigabitEthernet0/0/2, RPF nbr: 10.6.227.1`, and an incoming interface list, which includes `TenGigabitEthernet0/0/2`, with the status of `Accepting/Sparse`.